# Can't detect click events on PublisherAdView

Tags: java, android, admob, google-play-services, ads

I've been attempting to attach an `onClickListener` to a `PublisherAdView` as follows:

```
// Initialized PublisherAdView and loaded request successfully.

adView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // Perform some logging for testing purposes.
    }
});
```

However, none of the breakpoints I've set in the body of `onClick` are ever triggered, and none of my log messages appear either, implying that `onClick` is never called. Am I missing some sort of configuration, or does `PublisherAdView` just not support `OnClickListener`s?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @Brian Cooley: I never did before I moved onto a new project, but looking through the most recent documentation for this API, depending on your use case you may be able to use the PublisherAdView's AppEventListener

Comment: Thanks. I also found the method `onAdLeftApplication` in AdListener which seems to work for my use case.